# set jQuery cookie for each checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, checkbox

I have a simple jQuery function that toggles classes based on checkbox states. Here's the code:

**jQuery:**

```
  $('input[name$="bg-noise-option"]').click(function(){
    var targetClass = $(this).data('at');
    $('.' + targetClass).toggleClass('bg-noise');
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option" data-at="page-wrap" checked>
      Body <br>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option" data-at="btn">
      Elements <br>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option" data-at="header, .navbar">
      Top Header <br>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option" data-at="page-header-wrap">
      Page Header <br>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option" data-at="site-footer">
      Footer <br>
    </label>
  </div>
```

**Question:**
How to create a cookie for each checkbox checked? I'm simply trying to give these checkboxes some memory... not sure of the best way.

I suspect some type of `.each(function)` should do it, but I'm still quite the javascript novice. I've tried the following:

```
$.each(function(){
  $.cookie('bg-noise-cookie', $(this).data('at'), {expires:365, path: '/'});
})
```

But of course that only creates one cookie for the most recently checked box. How to create a unique cookie for each? Or do I even need to? Perhaps there's a way to store them in one cookie (an array?) and then simply reference the array on page load to check the checkboxes?

Much obliged for insight.

Comment: Why not create a json string, and every time the user clicks on a checkbox a new json string is created storing the data of all currently selected checkboxes and replaces the current cookie value.   Then when the page reloads you can use that json to check which ones need to be checked.   That way you only need one cookie for all of them.

Comment: @RagingCelt, I like this approach... very clean. Hadn't even crossed my mind. But I've no experience working with `.json` from javascript. Perhaps you could include the necessary code in an answer? Otherwise, perhaps you could share some helpful resources for such an approach? Many thanks.

Comment: Sure.   Give me some time and I'll cobble something together unless someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you're using the [JQuery Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), since I see you referenced it in your question.

Here you are.   Creates and alters a single cookie file upon any checkbox click, storing only those data-at values that correspond to checked boxes.

On page load, it retrieves that JSON string, coverts it back to an object, then loops through, applying a check to the box of any matching attribute.

Code tested and working.

HTML: I added '[]' to your checkboxes to properly group them and removed any default checked boxes.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option[]" data-at="page-wrap">
        Body <br>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option[]" data-at="btn">
        Elements <br>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option[]" data-at="header, .navbar">
        Top Header <br>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option[]" data-at="page-header-wrap">
        Page Header <br>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="bg-noise-option[]" data-at="site-footer">
        Footer <br>
    </label>
</div>
```

JQuery: using $.cookie() plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // check for cookie on load
        if( $.cookie('chk_ar') ) {
            console.log($.cookie('chk_ar'));
            var chk_ar = $.cookie('chk_ar');

            // convert string to object
            chk_ar = $.parseJSON(chk_ar);
            console.log(chk_ar);

            // loop through and apply checks to matching sets
            $.each(chk_ar, function(index, value) {
                console.log(value);
                $('input').filter('[data-at="'+value+'"]').prop('checked', true);
            });
        }
    });

    // handle checkboxes
    $('input[name="bg-noise-option[]"').on('click', function() {
        var check_array = [];

        // add to array
        $(':checked').each(function() {
            check_array.push($(this).attr('data-at'));
        });

        // stringify array object
        check_array = JSON.stringify(check_array);
        console.log(check_array);

        // set cookie
        $.cookie('chk_ar', check_array, {path:'/'});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: many thanks for this. Being a javascript novice, this took me a while to get my head around. I failed to mention in my question that these checkboxes are in a toggleable div, with a simple `off` and `on` radio toggle for showing/hiding it. This added some complexity, but I've finally gotten it working. Can post the code, should it be helpful for others, but will refrain unless requested since it's outside the scope of my question. Anways, again, many thanks. Now I know a little about storing and parsing `JSON` :)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Javascript (or any language, really) can pretty daunting at first, but once it clicks, it's amazing how easy it all really is.   Toughest part is following the logic.  I could probably be a bit more explanatory when I comment my code on this site for novices. :)