# jQuery cookie from data-attributes using JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, cookies, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I have a series of divs that are toggled with Bootstrap's toggle jQuery. I need to create a cookie that remembers and preserves the toggled state of the divs. I'm attempting to set the toggled states to a `json` string (as recommended by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776636/set-jquery-cookie-for-each-checkbox#comment34726794_22776636)) in order to only have one cookie.

I've run into a snag that I can't seem to get passed. The `json` array is getting created, but it's always one behind, so to speak.

**The jQuery:**

$('#style-widget [data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function() {

```
var check_open_divs = [];
var toggled_div = $('#style-widget [data-toggle="collapse"]:not(.collapsed)');

// PROBLEM BELOW ▼ -- on initial click the data attribute is not going into the array
// on second click (when the class 'toggled' is being added by Bootstrap code) the 
// data attribute is added to the array

$(toggled_div).each(function() {
  check_open_divs.push($(this).attr('data-target'));
});

// stringify array object
check_open_divs = JSON.stringify(check_open_divs);

$.cookie('bg-noise-div-state', check_open_divs, {expires:365, path: '/'});
```

});

**The (simplified) HTML:**

```
<div id="style-widget">

  <!-- div one -->
  <p title="click to toggle" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#background-noise-wrap">Background Noise</p>
  <div id="background-noise-wrap" class="collapse">
    <!-- content here, removed for brevity -->
  </div>

  <!-- div two -->
  <p title="click to toggle" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extra-header-selection-wrap">Extra Header</p>
  <div id="extra-header-selection-wrap" class="collapse">
    <div class="selection-wrap first">
     <!-- content here, removed for brevity -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- div three -->
  <p title="click to toggle" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#wide-or-boxed-wrap">Wide or Boxed?</p>
  <div id="wide-or-boxed-wrap" class="collapse">
    <p>Header &amp; Footer</p>
    <div id="wide-boxed-selection-wrap">
      <!-- content here, removed for brevity -->
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

By default the divs are collapsed, which is why they initially have the `.collapsed` class. In pseudo-code thinking:

```
1. create function on click of collapse toggle (the p tag)
2. select divs that are not collapsed
3. save these to a json string, then cookie
4. check for this cookie on page load to persist the toggled states
```

Much obliged for any insights.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the json is one behind.   I tested it and it's working (although I had to remove `#style-widget` from the click event to get it to work properly), but nothing is going into the json string because the elements its selecting all have the `.collapsed` class.

Also, make sure you end a javascript line with a `;`.   You're missing ones on `var toggled_div` and the `$.cookie()`.

Can you explain more specifically what the problem is?

Comment: Updated question to better explain. Added `#style-widget` div which I had previously forgotten from the illustration code. Also explained the logic behind having the `.collapsed` class and checking for toggled divs by selecting those that had the `.collapsed' class removed (and this is where the problem seems to be).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you're saying the problem is that when you toggle the div, it's not reflecting properly in the json string until you click it again?

Comment: Correct. Upon the first toggle `console.log(check_open_divs);` simply returns `[]` and on the second toggle of the same or different div the data attribute in input into the json sting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encapsulate the cookie creation into a function and then call the function *after* toggling the class.

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function() {

    // toggle your div class here
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded collapsed');

    // call function to store value
    storeState();

 });

function storeState() {
    var check_open_divs = [];
    var toggled_div = $('#style-widget [data-toggle="collapse"]:not(.collapsed)');

    $(toggled_div).each(function() {
      check_open_divs.push($(this).attr('data-target'));
    });

    // stringify array object
    check_open_divs = JSON.stringify(check_open_divs);
    console.log(check_open_divs);

    $.cookie('bg-noise-div-state', check_open_divs, {expires:365, path: '/'});
}
```

Comment: I have no words :) Incredible. Did the trick. Knew it was something rather simple. Thank you. A quick follow-up, if I may: Calling the function `storeState()` here before it's been declared seems a bit counter-intuitive... why does this not cause any problem?

Comment: The function might be parsed by the browser after the click event, but the function is already loaded by the time you trigger the click event, so it's sitting in memory waiting to be accessed.  You're not calling the file itself every time you run javascript.   The entire page (and browser) is sitting in memory, where it stores and executes script.

Comment: It really doesn't matter where a function goes.   I place mine at the bottom of scripts because I find it makes for better readability and searchability when event code and functions are separate.